# Passing Buffer to struct in C

Tags: c, struct, buffer

I have the following Code

```
    int main( void )
{

    Queue * queue1=createQueue(4000,100);
     char * buffer;
    //create the parameters 
    //

    Parameters DataToSend[1]={{queue1,&buffer}};
}

     typedef struct
{

    Queue * QueueHandle;

    void * content;
}Parameters;
```

I want to pass the buffer content or address to the DataToSend 
How can I do that in my code I got the following error 
The Error in the line

**Parameters DataToSend**

> expression must have a constant value

Comment: Please format your code. Please indicate the line producing the error. Please incorporate the definitions of the relevant types.

Comment: how about `Parameters DataToSend = {queue1, buffer };`

Comment: @SouravGhosh `&buffer` is not a constant expression, neither is `buffer`. It will lead to the same problems.

Answer (score 0):

C89 requires the initializers of a structure object (and more generally for objects of aggregate and union types) to be constant expressions.

```
Parameters DataToSend[1]={{queue1,&buffer}};
```

`queue1` is an object and so is not a constant expression; it is not valid in C89.

C99 changed this rule and allows structure initializers that are not constant expressions. Check with your compiler documentation if you can switch to C99 mode.